# Trying to pass an instance value and it is not working

Tags: ruby

Relevant code below.  I have the instance variable, @replace and the attr_accessor replace.  In the method `get_player`, @replace has the correct value I'm looking to get, as far as puts and p could show me.  I 'think' it should set the instance variable.  for the class but it is not. When I try to use it in `refresh_board` it is empty.

```
class Board < TicTacToe

  attr_accessor :current_player, :replace, :board, :player

  def initialize(board = "
                       ╔════╦════╦════╗
                       ║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║  
                       ╠════╬════╬════╣
                       ║ 4  ║ 5  ║ 6  ║
                       ╠════╬════╬════╣
                       ║ 7  ║ 8  ║ 9  ║
                       ╚════╩════╩════╝")
       @board = board
       @player = player
       @replace = replace
  end

  def refresh_board(x)
    @board.gsub!(/#{x}/, "#{@replace}")
    display_board
  end

  def get_player(a)
    @current_player = a
    if @current_player == 'Player 1'
      @replace = 'X'
    else 
      @replace = 'O'
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not instantiating another instance so maybe that is why. At this point, with a lot of searching I've yet to come up with a solution.  If it wasn't for gsub doing the swap out I'd just pass a variable with a calling method.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code. Your initialize method only has one parameter, but your code assumes three. Why you use a depiction of a board as input instead of a 2d array is beyond me. `get_player` isn't really a function of a board, is it? Either you need to rename your model or pull that logic out.

Comment: Caveat, it's my first foray into OOD and still very new to Ruby.  I didn't include all the code.  You are right though, `get_player` doesn't sound like a function of the board but it's a stop gap at this point. `class Player` (not shown) is where I'm deriving the status from, at least in my current strategy.  I guess, perhaps not initializing those variables is part of my problem. I'm work on that first.  As for the board is just a personal choice.

Comment: I think your idea to have a string literal containing the board *layout* and then replacing each element is not bad at all--but you need to separate your logical Board object (which could just be a 3x3 array, or a 9-element array with accessors to translate that to x and y coordinates) from the display of the Board, or you'll never get this thing off the ground. 

Then to display your game you can simply run through your logical board from positions 0 to 8, perform the replacements on a copy of your template, and output the result.

Comment: Thanks @struthersneil .  I had most of the important stuff working but in a procedural structure.  I do like your idea so maybe it's time to start thinking that one through.  I'm curious why you say it won't get off the ground otherwise.  No problems though if you don't wish to elaborate.

Comment: I've just seen a lot of tic tac toe projects over the years. Biggest hurdle for students is usually the separation of modelling the game and displaying the game/collecting input. Think in Model / View / Controller terms. Model in this case is the board and rules. View is the logical board applied to a template and output to console. Controller is the game loop, user input, connecting the parts.

Comment: @struthersneil I did a pass through on the Sandi Metz book (Practical OOD. for Ruby) I believe that for the most part I created the objects that made sense, at least to me ;).  Class wise (and I did try to think more about messages) I have a player, play (which is the loop and user input), a score and instruction classes.  I had briefly looked at some examples online, though not to closely as I didn't want to be influenced at this point, but I noticed the ones that had a 'board'.  It's more then possible those were arrays translated onto a template.  Hadn't thought about that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of modeling a board using an array as input, and just using the template for output:

```
class Board

  attr_accessor :board

  def initialize(board = [" "]*10)
    @board = board
    @template = "
         ╔════╦════╦════╗
         ║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║  
         ╠════╬════╬════╣
         ║ 4  ║ 5  ║ 6  ║
         ╠════╬════╬════╣
         ║ 7  ║ 8  ║ 9  ║
         ╚════╩════╩════╝"
  end

  def add_move(square, token)
    raise "Square already taken" if @board[square] != " "
    @board[square] = token
  end

  def to_s
    @template.tr("123456789", @board[1..9].join)
  end
end
```

You interact with it this way:

```
> b = Board.new
> puts b

     ╔════╦════╦════╗
     ║    ║    ║    ║
     ╠════╬════╬════╣
     ║    ║    ║    ║
     ╠════╬════╬════╣
     ║    ║    ║    ║
     ╚════╩════╩════╝

> b.add_move(1, "X")
> puts b

     ╔════╦════╦════╗
     ║ X  ║    ║    ║
     ╠════╬════╬════╣
     ║    ║    ║    ║
     ╠════╬════╬════╣
     ║    ║    ║    ║
     ╚════╩════╩════╝
```

Storing your board as an array will pay off if you need to apply logic to it, such as determining a winner. Also the removal of any player-related stuff is a proper separation of concerns.

Comment: Very cool and appreciated.  Yes, determining a winner is the next step for me.   I think your recommendation would certainly cut down on steps as well as processing.  I mean, I already have multiple arrays, one for X player and one for O player, plus one that holds the winning combinations. Plus there is the issue which your code covers that was in my mind, what if the square is already taken.  It's a good touch to the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was instance variable and not initializing.  However even initializing the @replace variable didn't seem to help. I found [this article](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) that helps clarify my understanding of instance variables and in particular class instance variables.  I think they are a better fit for that particular part of my code, though I can't explain they why very well.

Now in class Board I declare a class instance variable

```
class Board < TicTacToe
  class << self; attr_accessor :replace end
  @replace = nil
  # rest of code
end
```

Then assign the variable to Object#instance_variable and call it:

```
def refresh_board(x)
    @board.gsub!(/#{x}/, "#{Board.replace}")
    display_board
    end
```

Hopefully soon I'll have a clear view of when to use class instance variables and when to use instance instance variables.